# Try catch when opening a text file for read

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code that is attempts to open a file on our network and what I am trying to do is put this into a try|catch block and I am running into a problem.  When I try run my code I get an error:  The name 'readProfile' does not exist in the current context (CS0103).

I know that since I am defining my streadreader object (readProfile) in the TRY of the try|catch block that I am not able to access the object but I don't know how to fix that.  What I am trying to do is catch an error if I am unable to open the file (if someone else has it open, for example).  Here is my code:

```
        try {
            StreamReader readProfile = new System.IO.StreamReader(ProDirectory.ToString() + @"\" + myProFile.ToString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            datalogger.Fatal(DateTime.Now.ToString() +  ":  Error while attempting to read file - " + ProDirectory.ToString() + @"\" + myProFile.ToString() + " The error is - "  + ex.ToString());
        }
```

If I remove the try|catch block, the code runs fine and does what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define variables outside the try, and then instantiate them inside:

```
StreamReader readProfile;
try
{
    readProfile = new System.IO.StreamReader(ProDirectory.ToString() + @"\" + myProFile.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    datalogger.Fatal(DateTime.Now.ToString() +  ":  Error while attempting to read file - " + ProDirectory.ToString() + @"\" + myProFile.ToString() + " The error is - "  + ex.ToString());
    // whatever you want to do with readProfile here. Of course, if the issue was that it couldn't create it, it still won't have been created...
}
```

Comment: Correct as a direct answer but not a good pattern/practice. At least add a `throw;` to the catch block.

Comment: Well, you cannot do "whatever you want" when accessing readProfile within catch block due to "Use of unassigned local variable 'readProfile'" error.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the StreamReader outside the try block but leave the assignment inside it.